# Script for Finding ADGroup Members, Need Way to Allow Input through Window?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am decent at making one-liners in PowerShell, but no so much stringing multiple functions together.

Raw code I came up with to get `ADGroupMembers` (From Active Directory):

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "AD Group Name Here" | select name
```

And I am familiar with using `Read-Host -Prompt`

But was looking for some guidance on how I can run a script, type in a group name, and receive the list from AD.
Any help would be appreciated!

Tried this, but it is probably horribly syntactically incorrect:

```
Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Group Name'
>> Get-ADGroupMember -identity Get-Host
```

Not sure where to go to allow input, receive output from the main script.

Comment: Store the result of the prompt in a variable. $GroupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Group Name'. And the use the variable in the command. Get-ADGroupMember -identity $GroupName. Or if you want it in one line: Get-ADGroupMember -identity (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Group Name')

Answer (score 0):

$groupname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Group Name'

Get-ADGroupMember -identity '$groupname'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).